# BroadcastReceiver for "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" received, when phone is idle

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, location, broadcastreceiver

I have a tracking app, that uses the GPS, and by using geofences, and a low power GPS, I know when the user moves and I start tracking him.
Yesterday I made a BroadcastReceiver for AirplaneMode, and the GPS, in order to now to stop my foreground service.
This is the code that I have:

```
    public class AirplaneModeAndGPSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Boolean airplaneMode = Utils.isAirplaneModeOn(context);
        Boolean gps = Utils.isGPSActive(context);
        Utils.appendLog("AirplaneModeBroadcastReceiver called. Airplane Mode: " + airplaneMode + " / gps state: " + gps, "I", Constants.TRACKER);
        if (airplaneMode || !gps) {
            if (null == PSTrip.getActiveTrip()) {
                PSLocationService.getInstance(context).locations.clear();
                PSGeofenceTransitionsIntentService.getInstance(context).removeGeofences(context);
                PSLocationService.getInstance(context).removeGeofenceFromDB(PSGeofenceTransitionsIntentService.geofenceRequestID);
                PSLocationService.getInstance(context).setTrackingEnabled(false);
            }
        } else {
            if (PSApplicationClass.getInstance().isAutoPilotAllowed() || PSTrip.getActiveTrip() != null)
                PSLocationService.getInstance(context).setTrackingEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked my logs, and I noticed, that for most phones it works fine.
BUT I have a LeEco Le2: https://www.gsmarena.com/leeco_le_2-8053.php
And I noticed that after I turn the screen off, and the phone becomes idle for too long. I get an event here, which turns then the tracking off because the "GPS" becomes OFF. And when I open the screen and unlock the phone, I get a GPS ON intent. Why does this happen, and is it possible to force the phone not to do that?
I can't know if the user manually turned the GPS off, or it was turned from this behavior, so I can't really try to start it again. So I'm looking for any other workarounds